# Cake PHP adding links to tree output

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to add links to a Tree output list.

In addition to the links I get the  **&nbsp's** included in the output

So that it looks like this:

```
**My Categories
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fun
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sport
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Surfing
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Extreme knitting**
```

**etc.....**

I don't want that obviously, but I do want to keep the nested output relationship.

Below is code:

**Controller**

```
<?php

class CategoriesController extends AppController {
 public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function index() {

      $this->set('output', $this->Category->generateTreeList(null, null, null, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'));
    }
}

?>
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($output as $data): ?>
<ul>

<?php echo $this->Html->link($data,
array('controller' => 'data', 'action' => 'view', $data)); ?>



</ul>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($data); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a tree helper to output your tree as ul/li including links.
See http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/02/17/cakephp-and-tree-structures/

generateTreeList() - as documented - is a quick way to create a dropdown select ready list, not a tree.

Comment: I'm trying to use your TreeHelper. Where do I put this TreeHelper file? In the helpers folder or the Plug in folder? Neither seems to be working. I put this in the controller:   public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Tools.Tree');   EDIT...When I use just 'Tree' instead of Tools.Tree it seems to be reading it. But I am now wondering why the documentation said to do otherwise.

Comment: Read the Setup part again. As a beginner you might want to drag and drop the whole plugin for now.

Comment: I went back and read it again and went slowly and did everything in the setup. I added CakePlugin::loadAll() to the bootstrap.php file. I added public $actsAs = array('Tree') to the Model. I added public $helpers = array('Tools.Tree'); to the controller. I then of course copied the entire code file and put it in App/Plugin directory. I get an error saying that the Tools plugin is not being loaded.

Comment: You are probably very new to Cake. It's important that you are running with debug = 2. Also, make sure you got all the basics covered. you might want debug if your bootstrap code gets properly executed etc. Also clear the cache once in a while to make sure.

Comment: Yes, I started playing with cake a few weeks ago and barley have the basics down. I don't know what debug=2 means nor what file to find that in

Comment: EDIT:  I have Configure::write('debug', 2);  in the core.php file.